# How to make horizontal scrollbar for multiple rows and columns in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, grid, frontend

I want multiple rows and columns to be horizontally scrolled by only one scroll bar. I could managed to make scrollbar for only one row and multiple columns
I tried the following but i could only make the scrollbar for only row.
the given below is the code i tried

```css
.page {
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
}

.hs {
  list-style: none;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 10% 2rem 0%;
}

.hs .item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 0.75rem;
  height: 100%;
  white-space: normal;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 15px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
  background-color: gray;
}

.li {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container page">
  <ul class="hs">
    <li class="item">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 ">
        <div class="card border-0" style="width: 15rem;">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="images/image 25.png" alt="Card image cap">
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="item">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 ">
        <div class="card border-0" style="width: 15rem;">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="images/image 25.png" alt="Card image cap">
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="item">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 ">
        <div class="card border-0" style="width: 15rem;">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="images/image 25.png" alt="Card image cap">
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>


    <li class="item">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 ">
        <div class="card border-0" style="width: 15rem;">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="images/image 25.png" alt="Card image cap">
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>


    <li class="item">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 ">
        <div class="card border-0" style="width: 15rem;">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="images/image 25.png" alt="Card image cap">
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>


    <li class="item">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 ">
        <div class="card border-0" style="width: 15rem;">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="images/image 25.png" alt="Card image cap">
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>


    <li class="item">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 ">
        <div class="card border-0" style="width: 15rem;">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="images/image 25.png" alt="Card image cap">
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="item">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 ">
        <div class="card border-0" style="width: 15rem;">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="images/image 25.png" alt="Card image cap">
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="item">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 ">
        <div class="card border-0" style="width: 15rem;">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="images/image 25.png" alt="Card image cap">
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="item">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 ">
        <div class="card border-0" style="width: 15rem;">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="images/image 25.png" alt="Card image cap">
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give height and width to your `<ul>` tag. That will set your height. Then you need to style the ul like `overflox-y: scroll;`. This will make your list as scrollbar. If wont work try `overflow-y: auto;`.

example

```css
ul{
  height: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

li{
height: 50px;
border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content = "ie=edge">
        <title> Keat </title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <ul>
          <li>Li-1</li>
          <li>Li-2</li>
          <li>Li-3</li>
          <li>Li-4</li>
          <li>Li-5</li>
          <li>Li-6</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

in div tag u can use these properties
{

```
   <div class="my-custom-scrollbar my-custom-scrollbar-primary">
```

}

in your style tag use this code

{

```
.my-custom-scrollbar {
 position: relative;
 width: 800px;
 height: 400px;
 overflow: auto;
  }
```

}

Comment: <div class="scrollbar scrollbar-primary">
  <div class="force-overflow"></div>
</div> use this

Comment: .scrollbar {
margin-left: 30px;
float: left;
height: 300px;
width: 65px;
background: #fff;
overflow-y: scroll;
margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.force-overflow {
min-height: 450px;
}